# VB.net Updating same ID different expiration

Tags: vb.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrKqk.png)The first picture is my inventory which is same `ItemID` different `Expiration`

[image]

And the Second picture is my Transaction which you can see the `Quantity` is 297, why my quantity is 297 because the first `BatchID` is 1 which `Quantity` is 12 and the second is `BatchID` 2 which has 285 `Quantity` and i use `SUM(Quantity)` in `Transaction` to make it no redundant.

[image]

now my problem is how can i code this.

i have first `BatchID` and the `Quantity` has 12pcs the second `BatchID` has 285pcs total of 297 now i want to buy 15pcs what will happen if i buy that 15pcs the first `BatchID` now has 0pcs and the second `BatchID` has 282....

In my program it will -3pcs and 285pcs

The last picture is my code for update the quantity please help me Thank very much

Comment: You will have to distribute your deductions to -12 and -3.

Comment: whaat do you mean?

Comment: Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT products.BatchID,batch.ItemID,batch.Item,batch.Description,batch.Dosage,batch.Indication,products.Classification,SUM(products.Quantity) AS Qty,products.Price,products.ExpireDate FROM batch INNER JOIN products ON batch.ItemID = products.ItemID WHERE Quantity <> 0 Group by ItemID Order By products.BatchID ASC, products.Item ASC,products.ExpireDate ASC", cn)
            Dim adp As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            adp.Fill(dt)
            dgv_productList.DataSource = dt
This is from Transaction Query

Comment: Try
                If (cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then
                    cn.Open()
                End If

                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE products SET Quantity=(Quantity- '" & SubQty & "') WHERE BatchID = '" & ID & "'", cn)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Product()
                cn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

Comment: Can you edit those comments into the question?

Comment: Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(
"SELECTproducts.BatchID,batch.ItemID,batch.Item,
batch.Description,batch.Dosage,batch.Indication,
products.Classification,SUM(products.Quantity) AS Qty,
products.Price,products.ExpireDate FROM batch 
INNER JOIN products ON batch.ItemID = products.ItemID WHERE Quantity <> 0 Group by ItemID 
Order By products.BatchID ASC, 
products.Item ASC,products.ExpireDate ASC", cn)
            
Dim adp As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dt As New DataTable
adp.Fill(dt) This is first 2nd picture

Comment: Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE products SET Quantity=(Quantity- '" & SubQty & "') WHERE BatchID = '" & ID & "'", cn)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
 Product()
cn.Close()
this code when i click purchase button it will update the Qty from inventory table

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the record counts for each batch from the db, and determine how much you need to deduct from them. Database tables won't "know" that you mean to share the Qty field for the same ItemID when performing an update (But you can put that kind of logic into a stored procedure).

Some pseudocode may be more useful

```
Dim totalQty as Integer = 15
'Open a new SqlConnection
'Query for all rows for ItemID = 5 and put them into a data table variable "dataTable"
'Close the connection

Dim quantsToDeduct as new Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer) 'Consider using a Tuple<int, int, int> if you need to also calculate the price of these also.
For each DataRow in "dataTable"
  Dim rowQty as Integer = Convert.ToInt32(row["Quantity"])
  Dim qtyToDeduct As Integer = 0
  If totalQty - rowQty >= 0 Then 
     qtyToDeduct = totalQty
     quantsToDeduct.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["BatchID"), qtyToDeduct)
     totalQty = totalQty - qtyToDeduct
  Else 
     qtyToDeduct = rowQty
     quantsToDeduct.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["BatchID"), qtyToDeduct)
     totalQty = totalQty - qtyToDeduct     
  End If

  If totalQuantity <= 0 Exit For 
End For

For Each quantToDeduct in quantsToDeduct
' Issue the update statement for the batchID (quantToDeduct.Key) and the quantity (quantToDeduct.Value)
End For
```

A few other points...

- The above bit of code should probably be wrapped in a TransactionScope, as we are reading data, calculating something with it, and then performing an update to it based on the data originally read.
- Quantities for goods may not always be integers (as is the case when items are sold by weight or can be sold as a partials), so consider using decimal for the Quantity field
- You may want to deduct from the quantities in the order of ExpirationDate so that the oldest stock is sold first.

Comment: Hi btw what is TOTALQTY as Integer = 15 mean?

Comment: Per your question "now i want to buy 15pcs ", thats the total quantity you want to deduct across the rows.